# Reaper: Convert split items to regions?

Tags: conversion, reaper

Is it possible to convert split items/sections in timeline to regions or markers so they can be rendered as marker points inside a wav file?

This would be a huge time saver for me because I use Sony Vegas to add narration in videos, and being able to use the same marker cuts makes things so much easier.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of any way to easily do that in the program.  However, since the project files are simply text it should be easy enough to write a program to parse the file and create markers to match the items.

Each item starts with the position property.

```
<ITEM
  POSITION 234.73069114906761
```

When adding a marker through the UI, you would see a dialog like this:

[image: add marker dialog]

This will add a marker which looks like this:

[image]

The markers are all near the beginning of the file.  In my project they are between the <TEMPOENVEX...> and <PROJBAY...> sections.

```
MARKER 1 38.04082125863206 "marker1" 0 0
MARKER 2 133.10227128138141 "marker2" 0 0
MARKER 3 183.21268644230756 "marker3" 0 0
```

As you can see from the code each line contains the ID, Position and Name.

I added marker 1 and 3 from the UI.  Marker 2 was added in code using the position of one of the items.  Marker 2 showed up just fine in the UI when the project was reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

From the Actions menu you can choose Show Action List. You can type in Regions in the filter box, and from the filtered actions you can select "Markers: Insert separate regions for each selected item".